# Search list of dictionaries using string and append it into another list of the same format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of objects

```
array = [

    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-1', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user1', 'UserId': '456'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user2', 'UserId': '789'},
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-22', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-3344', 'UserId': '456'} 

]
```

I want to search username starting with sns and seperate it into another list. can someone let me know how to do this

expected output:

```
array1 = [

    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-1', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-22', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-3344', 'UserId': '456'} 
]

array2 = [

    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user1', 'UserId': '456'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user2', 'UserId': '789'},

]
```

Comment: "startswith" works just fine , thank you peeps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
array = [

    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-1', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user1', 'UserId': '456'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user2', 'UserId': '789'},
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-22', 'UserId': '123'}, 
    {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-3344', 'UserId': '456'} 

]

array1 = [x for x in array if x['UserName'].startswith('sns')]
array2 = [x for x in array if not x['UserName'].startswith('sns')]
```

Output:

```
>>> array1
[{'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-1', 'UserId': '123'},
 {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-22', 'UserId': '123'},
 {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'sns-3344', 'UserId': '456'}]
>>> array2
[{'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user1', 'UserId': '456'},
 {'Path': '/', 'UserName': 'user2', 'UserId': '789'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not pythonic, still to be clear on the logic, or you can refer the other answers:

```
array1=[]
array2=[]
for elem in array:
    if elem['UserName'].startswith('sns'):
        print(array1.append(elem))
    else:
        print(array2.append(elem))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this:

```py
array1 = []
array2 = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i]['UserName'].startswith('sns'):
        array1.append(array[i])
    else:
        array2.append(array[i])


print('array1', array1)
print('array2', array2)
```

Comment: He needs the UserName to start with 'sns', Your code prints the UserName contains 'sns', irrespective of its position

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
array1 = []
array2 = []
for dictionary in array:
    if 'sns' in dictionary['UserName']:
        array1.append(dictionary)
    else:
        array2.append(dictionary)
```

Comment: Username should start with 'sns', but your code will also take the username which consist of 'sns' in between username. Like- 'User1-sns'